# Spring boot on Docker unable to connect with MySQL. Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM gradle:8.4.0-jdk17 AS build

WORKDIR /home/cabeceira

COPY build.gradle .
COPY settings.gradle .
COPY src /home/cabeceira/src

RUN gradle clean build -x test

FROM openjdk:17

WORKDIR /home/cabeceira

COPY --from=build /home/cabeceira/build/libs/api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

With this docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app-dev:
    build:
      context: ./
    image: 'nlperri/cabeceira-api:latest'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    networks:
      - springapimysql-net
    environment:
      - >-
        spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/cabeceira?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    depends_on:
      mysqldb:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - '.m2:/root/.m2'
  
  mysqldb:
    image: 'mysql:8.0'
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=cabeceira
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    networks:
      - springapimysql-net
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD
        - mysqladmin
        - ping
        - '-h'
        - localhost
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
networks:
  springapimysql-net:
```

Locally I'm able to connect to database normally, but when I pushed the image to dockerhub the application does not start with some connection errors:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:175) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:446) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar!/:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:437) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar!/:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar!/:6.2.13.Final]
    ... 120 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:62) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:150) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:166) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:945) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    ... 133 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysqldb
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1367) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1301) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    ... 136 common frames omitted
```

I also have application-properties like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/cabeceira?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

I have no idea what could be. Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks!

Fail to connect to database